# Binary tree level order traversal algoritm

Tags: java, programming-challenge, tree, breadth-first-search, time-limit-exceeded

I am trying to solve this [Binary tree lever order traversal](http://oj.leetcode.com/problems/binary-tree-level-order-traversal-ii/):

> ```
> Given binary tree {3,9,20,#,#,15,7},
>     3
>    / \
>   9  20
>     /  \
>    15   7
> return its bottom-up level order traversal as:
> [
>   [15,7]
>   [9,20],
>   [3],
> ]
> ```

How can I improve the speed of the code below? It always gives me a time exceed error.

```java
/**
 * Definition for binary tree
 * public class TreeNode {
 *     int val;
 *     TreeNode left;
 *     TreeNode right;
 *     TreeNode(int x) { val = x; }
 * }
 */
public class Solution {

    public ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> levelOrderBottom(TreeNode root) {
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> tree = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
        Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<Integer>();
        ArrayList<Integer> node = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        this.iterateAll(root, stack);

        while (!stack.empty()) {
            if (stack.peek() != null) {
                node.add(stack.pop());
                if (!stack.isEmpty()) {
                    if (stack.peek() != null) {
                        tree.add(node);
                        node = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                    } else {
                        stack.pop();
                        if (!stack.isEmpty()) {
                            if (stack.peek() != null) {
                                tree.add(node);
                                node = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    tree.add(node);
                }
            } else {
                stack.pop();
            }
        }
        return tree;
    }

        public Stack<Integer> iterateAll(TreeNode root, Stack<Integer> stack) {
        if (root != null) {
            stack.push(root.val);
            if (root.right != null) {
                iterateAll(root.right, stack);
            } else {
                stack.push(null);
            }

            if (root.left != null) {
                iterateAll(root.left, stack);
            } else {
                stack.push(null);
            }
        }
        return stack;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on number of nodes in your tree, recursive post-order traversal of the tree, might let you run into problems on the stack. If the number of nodes is huge, you might need to consider a non-recursive post-order traversal.

Have a look at http://leetcode.com/2010/10/binary-tree-post-order-traversal.html, which describes multiple solutions, both iterative and non-recursive.

On think to keep in mind is that the non-recursive algorithms use more memory, as it need to push nodes to a stack.

You might also consider doing a post-order tree traversal enumerator, but that might be for another day.

Comment: you might want to write a little sum up of your link, in case it goes down, I think some pseudocode or even just a short explanation of the algorithm would be enough.